# Error when installing NLTK on Windows10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, nltk

I am trying to install NLTK on Windows10 Pro 64 bit. It gives me following error.

> Python version -32 required, which was not found in the registry.

I have installed python 3.5.0 (32 bit) in my machine and have added following to path variable.
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\

Can anyone help me to proceed with NLTK installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a newcomer to Python, it may be simple (even if bigger) to use a pre-assembled Python Distribution.

For  example: 
Anaconda-4.2.0 in Python 3.5 "flavor" should have nltk in the box https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

Answer (score 0):

I am not running Windows 10, but rather Windows 8. However, I would like to share what I learned in recent days regarding the problems installing NLTK on a 64 bit Windows platform, because I believe it is probably applicable here (and to a number of other similar questions).

NLTK, the most recent version nltk-3.2.2.win32 (msi installer) will not install with a local 64-bit Python host (in other words, if you are on a Windows 64 platform and previously decided to install a 64 bit version of Python). However, it doesn't tell you that. It complains that Python 32 is required and cannot be found and then will not allow you to type in the path to your Python installation (mine is ActivePython-2.7.10.12-win64-x64). There is an excellent post that describes most of the solutions here [Fix for NLTK install on Win 64](http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/faq.html).

In a nutshell, you can uninstall your Python 64 bit installation and install a 32 bit, which is what NLTK really wants, or you can try to build the NLTK installation locally with pip install pyyaml nltk (see the post I linked above).

My contribution is to add that although you will end up with NLTK installed you likely will still not properly build pyyaml because it must compile and build a c code extension (a Windows dll which for Python extensions in c will be a pyd extension rather than dll in order to spare additonal confusion if the name intersects with another dll somewhere on the system). Windows systems have a confusing array of user directory paths and the compiler (even if you have MSVC installed and know how to use it) cannot find the necessary library files typically when it is called from distutils (one of the python build helpers that is called). You could save the error output on your command console session and try to manually point the appropriate configuration files at your local path, but a simpler approach in this case is to simply obtain the correct compiled file that pyyaml is trying to build. Your install process above will typically go ahead and put the pyyaml python files (the .py files) in your site-packages directory (under your local Python installation directory), so all you need to do is obtain the compiled file, which happens to be named _yaml.pyd, and insert it into your yaml directory (that is what the install process above created in my site-packages directory), where all the pyyaml Python files reside.

You can obtain the necessary file at [Python Packages, PyYAML 3.12](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML). At that page you will see a list of available PyYAML packages. You should select the one that is congruent with your Python, Windows and NLTK requirements, which in this case is PyYAML-3.12-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (since I am running a 64 bit Python on a 64 bit Windows platform; if you running 32 bit Python then use the win32 whl). A little more explanation is required. This looks like even more headache, but it actually is not. The whl file is simply a zip package that you can extract with 7-Zip or whatever zip extractor is on your system (right click on the downloaded file to explore possibilities). Just extract it on your desktop or the like and you will find three items inside. Two will be folders, which you can ignore (you might want to verify that the yaml folder has the identical .py files to the ones you installed earler in your site-packages directory with pip, but if you are installing the latest NTLK that should be true). The third item is your target, _yaml.pyd. Copy or move that into your ...site-packages/yaml/ directory (mine is "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\yaml"). Don't be concerned that all the other files there are .py or .pyc files. It will be right at home. The author of this PyYAML package, Kirill Simonov, has made the use of this c extension easier than usual, providing the hooks locally for you with a .py file (cyaml.py). cyaml.py imports all the c code by "from _yaml import CParser, CEmitter," so it will be happy to find the _yaml.pyd you just copied in without further annoyance. I ran the NLTK unit tests yesterday after executing this strategy and a few of the tests offered at the NLTK site and it was fairly happy (just need to download a few more corpora and the like, but you will discover that soon enough if your first import nltk works).

I note that I have used this chicanery to avoid the obtuse installation process on several other occasions when all I needed was a wheel package, i.e., I just got the appropriate wheel, extracted the files and place them appropriately in the Python installation (something mentioned as one attractive feature of the Wheel package format).

Answer (score -1):

You can try open the cmd as administrator and paste this command:

```
"C:\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip3" install nltk
```

Note: The installation directory of python in your case may be different. In my case the command was

```
"C:\Users\Faith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts" install nltk
```